# An external swf in Flash builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I embed an external swf in flash builder like so:

```
[Embed(source="assets/sounds/mytestswf.swf")]
private static var mySwf: Class;
```

How can I access it and add it to another sprite on stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think you need a loader, that's for libraries that are added at runtime. Embed compiles the assets directly in the swf, so `addChild(new mySwf());` is enough to add it to the the display object list.

obviously, you'd like to assign it to a variable, so

```
var $mySwf:mySwf = new mySwf();
addChild($mySwf);
```

On a side note, you should name your classes consistently. Class names start with the first letter capitalized, so you can tell it apart from variables

```
[Embed(source="/assets/sounds/mytestswf.swf")]
private static var MySwf: Class;
...
var $mySwf:MySwf = new MySwf();
addChild($mySwf);
```

Comment: on the new FB 4.7 I think you will need to add a slash at the beginning ("/assets/yourswif.swf") to prevent errors. Also make sure that you don t use relative paths like ../..

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to specify `mimeType="application/octet-stream"` on your `Embed`.  Then, you need to create a `Loader` instance and use the `Loader.loadBytes()` method to load the `ByteArray` associated with the embedded class:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new mySwf();
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.loadBytes(bytes);
addChild(loader);
```

Reference for learning: [Loader.loadBytes() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes%28%29)

Comment: See note above about adding `mimeType` declaration to the `Embed` call.

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't work" -- is there an error, or does code in the loaded SWF not execute, etc?