# import non-Adobe swf files into flash builder - actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, air, flash-builder

I am doing a ActionScript mobile project.

is there a way to import non-Adobe swf files into Flash Builder?

I tried this:

[An external swf in Flash builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842480/a-an-external-swf-in-flash-builder)

but  I get error:
"Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MySwfMyg."

is it because i am using non-Adobe file - like Vectorian Giotto?

Thanks

Comment: @Lee Burrows , I reposted my question with the code included here:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636906/embedding-swf-into-flash-builder-type-was-not-found

Comment: you could have edited this question, but never mind - youve got your answer ;)